# How to embed pivot table in java web application using eclipse BIRT

Tags: java, eclipse, birt, pivot-table

I have few questions regarding the pivot table functionality of BIRT

1) My first requirement is i want to embed the pivot table in my application so that end user can create the pivot table. it must provide drag and drop support.
2)Pivot table should be dynamically generated for end users like excel.

Does eclispe birt has these features.

Answer (score 1):

The community edition of BIRT does not include these features.

The commercial version of Actuate - in particular, Actuate 11's BIRT Data Analyzer - does support this functionality. See [here](http://www.actuate.com/products/birt-user-experience/analytics/) for further details.